# Is it faster to run a windows program in windows or in WINE with a barebones OS?

Tags: wine

There are Linux bare-bones OS. I am considering running a windows program in one with wine to improve speed. Is this a reasonable concept?

Comment: Which bare-bone OS are you referring to?

Comment: @Anwar Archlinux

Answer (score 1):

This will depend very heavily on driver support in Wine, but my experience has been that Wine is often slightly slower, even with up to date drivers and the same hardware.  My presumption is that this occurs because Wine is less efficient at servicing Windows API calls than Windows is, often translating those calls to Linux API calls and passing them on (which inherently takes a small amount of time).

It's very possible this is dependent on version, on both sides and Wine version, so I can't call my experience definitive.

Answer (score 0):

No, -generally- wine is messy to get right, lots of tinkering and even then it is troublesome, and lacks the proper setup to be a full Windows alternative. As an example: For a game the driver needs to be optimal to get it running correctly. Running  Guild Wars in wine is possible. But for from optimal.

I would suggest installing virtualbox or vmware and install windows in that and use your software in that. You can allocate as much RAM as you need it and adjust the amount if needed.

The overhead of the full operating system is negligible compared to the ease of usage in regards to setting it up, maintaining it (backups, drivers, updating etc), and managing it.

Comment: That is just false; in the vast majority of cases, Wine "just works".

Comment: I agree with @Rinzwind. WINE is a waste of time. +1 to offset somebody's down vote.

Comment: @fkraiem no. That is false. Wine is a waste of time. Wine is 1 gigantic security hole. And virtualization is far superior than Wine. There is not a single reason to support the usage of Wine.

Comment: That is just nonsense coming from someone who probably was unlucky that an obscure, poorly coded program he wanted to use didn't work. Shrug. Would downvote again if I could.

Comment: @fkraiem a Virtualbox/vmware setup is far more superiour and that method targets the same audience that would want to use wine.  Less hassle setting up, less security issues,  easy backup, no messing with settings. Wine is a waste of resources. and why are you wasting time on a topic from 2016 that was closed as off topic?